# The easiest way to convert arrayList to object[][]

Tags: java, arraylist

I am receiving my data from the database in the type of

`Map<String,ArrayList<String>`

So, the columns' names are the keys, and the columns values are stored in the

```
ArrayList<String>
```

I need to convert these hash to `Object [][] data;` for presenting data.

I know, how simple solutions like loops work.
But i would like to know what is the shortest solution to convert

`ArrayList<String>` to `Object[][] data`

I am using **java 8.**

Let's say, at the beginning i have

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> res
```

**Point:**

I have the data in `ArrayList<String>` means that, I have access to data vertically, but i in `Object [][]` it is somehow horizontally.

As i said `res` is the database **table**, so `Object [][]` would be a **row**, meanwhile the `ArrayList<String>` is the column

Comment: As a starting point, you can use res.values().toArray() to get an ArrayList<String>[], but at that point you'd have to loop through the array to convert all of the arraylists to arrays.

Comment: Yes, the point is i have the values vertically, and i need to make it horizontally

Comment: You haven't really explained the relationship between your input and output. It might help to demonstrate a transformation using a standard loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Object[][] result = res.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .map(e -> e.getValue().toArray())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
                       .toArray(new Object[0][0]);
```

The resulting array has the dimension: `result[col][row]`. So when iterating:

```
for(int col = 0; col < result.length; col++) {
  for(int row = 0; y < result[col].length; row++){
     result[col][row]; //table cell 
  }
}
```

Comment: `res.values().stream().map(List::toArray).toArray(Object[][]::new)`

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 provides an efficient solution for converting it to a data object as stated well by @Gerald in the above answer. 
However, if you are also interested in doing this in the naive approach then I have implemented the code as follows.

```
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] arr1 = { "I", "am", "good" };
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    map.put("Max", new ArrayList<String>(list));

    arr1 = new String[]{"I", "am", "always", "excited"};
    list = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    map.put("Peter", new ArrayList<String>(list));

    System.out.println(map);
    // OUTPUT: {Max=[I, am, good], Peter=[I, am, always, excited]}

    Object[][] data = new Object[map.size()][];
    int i = 0;

    // iterate the map and store to Object data
    for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        data[i] = new Object[entry.getValue().size() + 1]; // number of records from list + (One) map key

        data[i][0] = entry.getKey(); // save key at '0'th index
        int j = 1;                   // iterate the ArrayList to save values in the same row. 
        for(String s : entry.getValue()) {
            data[i][j++] = s;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // Printing the data object
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // OUTPUT :
    //Max I am good 
    //Peter I am always excited
```